# sql server round

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

```
select round((cast(56/3 AS DECIMAL (4,2))),1)
```

is showing 18 output instead of 19 , where as actual value is 18.66. 
My Round function is not working 
please help.

Comment: How you got `18.66` . `select cast(56/3 AS DECIMAL (4,2))` returns `18`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `56/3` is an *integer* calculation which means no floating point numbers.

You need to use floating point numbers in the initial calculation e.g. `56.0/3`. Also, if you want to round to 19 then you need to round to the nearest *whole* number, `ROUND(x, 1)` will round to the first decimal place - you need to pass `0` to round up to 19.

```
SELECT ROUND((CAST(56.0/3 AS DECIMAL (4,2))),0)
```

Alternatively, you could switch [ROUND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175003.aspx) for [CEILING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189818.aspx)

```
select CEILING(CAST(56.0/3 AS DECIMAL(4,2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your section of the code:

```
CAST( 56/3 AS DECIMAL )
```

First evaluates the `56/3` which returns 18. This is then cast to decimal, giving 18.0.

You need to cast either the numerator or denominator before the division occurs.

The `round` function is working fine -- it's just not using the input you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

Convert one of your integer values before you divide the numbers:

```
select round(56/convert(DECIMAL (4,2),3),0);
```

If you do not so you divide integers which results in 18 not 18.66